# Contacts/ Notes & Attachments

Tags: page-layout, attachment, contact, related-list, notes

Is it possible to have all the 'Notes and Attachments' from the Account Object to be displayed on each subsequent Opportunity it is related to automatically- similar to a related list?

Also, is it possible to display all the contacts that were entered on the account level to show up on each related Opportunity that is created? Our environment does not use the Contact Roles. Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: No. Not without creating and inline VF page to display such items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use a visualforce page section to your opportunity page layout. You can use something along these lines with a standard controller:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false" tabStyle="Opportunity" 
       showQuickActionVfHeader="false" showChat="false">

       <apex:relatedList subject="{!Opportunity.Account}" list="CombinedAttachments"/>
</apex:page>
```

This will allow you to view the notes and attachments from the account (by taking advantage of the lookup relationship of opportunity to account). More information on related lists in Visualforce can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm). The same kind of page could be used to find information the account from the child contact.

Here is what it looks like in my sandbox:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this script! I tried it out in sandbox but received the below error Error: Cyclic page or component references '/apex/Show_Contacts_Notes_Attachments' are not allowed

Comment: Odd I just tested it in my sandbox and it worked fine. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: The error message comes up before I can even save the Visual Force Page

Comment: Are you using the code exactly as specified or are you doing something else with it (e.g. putting it into a component or another page). I looked around quickly and it looks like such an issue comes up when you have two <apex:page> tags

Comment: Looks like it works now! but i am only able to add it to a random section on the layout not to a related list, correct? Also, could please help with the Contacts now instead of notes & attachments

Comment: It doesn't have to be a random section on the layout, you can put it into any section you like. I would recommend having it in its own section (maybe at the bottom) with only 1 column. You can not add it to the normal list of related lists though; however, you can add other related lists to the same section.

You can reuse the same code in a different page essentially. You'll need to swap out "Opportunity" and use "Contact" in its place and the list parameter would need to be set to "Contacts" instead of CombinedAttachments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26357/discussion-between-jazzyj-and-jason-hardy).